# Proof for a Rank-One Decomposition Theorem of Positive (semi) Definite Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following result which I recently came across in a research paper in my area (Signal Processing)

> Let $X$ be a $N\times N$ positive semidefinite (psd) matrix whose rank
>   is $r$. Let $A$ be any symmetric $N\times N$ matrix. Then, there exist
>   a set of vectors $x_1,\dots,x_r$ such that \begin{align} X & =
>  \sum_{i=1}^{r}x_ix_i^T \\ x_i^TAx_i &=
>  \frac{\mbox{trace}\{AX\}}{r},~~~\forall i \end{align}

The following is the proof for it which I can't verify.

**Proof:**
Consider the following step-wise procedure whose inputs are $X$ and $A$.

$~~$0.$~~$ Inputs are $X$ (given $X\geq 0$, $rank(X)=r$) and $A$ (symmetric).

1. Decompose $X=RR^T$.
2. Generate the eigen decomposition $R^TAR=U\Lambda U^T$.
3. Let $h$ be any $N\times 1$ vector such that $\lvert h_i\rvert=1$ (each entry of $h$). Generate the vector $x_1$ and matrix $X_1$ as 
   \begin{align}
   x_1&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}}RUh \\
   X_1&=X-x_1x_1^T 
   \end{align}
4. Outputs are $X_1$ and $x_1$.

The paper then claims that

- $X_1$ is psd and has rank $r-1$
- $x_1^TAx_1=\frac{1}{r}trace(AX)$

**While I am able to verify the second claim, am not able to verify the first one? How is it true?** If this can be done, the rest of the proof is straight forward. I am looking for a rigorous proof.

Read this if you are interested to know where this proof heads. Now do the stepwise algorithm earlier with inputs $X_1$ and $A$ to get $x_2$ and $X_2$ such that \begin{align}X_2&=X_1-x_2x_2^T\\&=X-x_1x_1^T-x_2x_2^T\end{align} and $$x_2^TAx_2=\frac{1}{r-1}trace(AX_1)=\frac{1}{r}trace(AX)$$ Then the result of the paper is that you can do this procedure $r$ times and get a rank-one decomposition $$X=\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_ix_i^T$$ with the property $$x_i^TAx_i\,=\,\frac{1}{r}trace(AX),~\forall i$$for any given psd X with rank $r$ and any symmetrix $A$.

Comment: Have you tried it for $2x2$ matrices? It may simply be a mistake in the paper. Wouldn't the rank one decomposition of a general positive definite symmetric $2x2$ matrix be essentially unique (the axis of the ellipse)? Then there is no way to get the desired property for arbitrary $A$.

Comment: I am not talking about the SVD based rank one decomposition if that is what you meant. Consider $2\times 2$ matrices, the result states that you can always find two vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $X=x_1x_1^T+x_2x_2^T$ and $x_i^TAx_i=trace(A*X)/2,~\forall i$ for any $X\geq 0, rank(X)=2$ and symmetric $A$.

Comment: Sorry, please disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what's going on with the paper, but here is an argument regarding existence of such decompositions.

Given a rank one decomposition 
$$X = \sum_{i=1}^R x_ix_i^T$$
one has $\sum_{i=1}^R x_i^TAx_i = {\rm Trace}(AX)$, so the question is how to make these pairings $x_i^TAx_i$ equal to each other. Consider the minimum of the function
$$
\sum_{i} (x_i^TAx_i-\frac 1R{\rm Trace}(AX))^2
$$
over the set of all possible rank one decompositions of $X$ (which is easily a compact set). Suppose this minimum occurs at some $\{x_i\}$ and is positive.

By reindexing, we may assume that $x_1^TAx_1<\frac 1R {\rm Trace}(AX)$ and is the minimum of $x_i^TAx_i$ and that $x_2^TAx_2>x_1^TAx_1$.
Consider a small rotation $\alpha$: 
$$y_1(\alpha)=x_1 \cos \alpha + x_2 \sin \alpha,~ y_2(\alpha) = -x_1\sin\alpha + x_2\cos\alpha,$$
so that $y_1y_1^T+y_2y_2^T=x_1x_1^T+x_2x_2^T$. By minimality,
$$
 y_1^T(\alpha)Ay_1(\alpha)  \leq  x_1^TAx_1 
$$
at all sufficiently small $\alpha$, else we can move the pairings closer together by replacing $x_1$ and $x_2$
by $y_1$ and $y_2$ for small $\alpha$ and keeping $x_{>2}$, which would contradict the minimality. This first of all implies by differentiating at $\alpha=0$ that
$$
x_1^TAx_2=0.
$$
Thus we get 
$$
y_1^T(\alpha)Ay_1(\alpha) = x_1^TAx_1\cos^2\alpha + x_2^TAx_2\sin^2\alpha
=x_1^TAx_1 + (x_2^TAx_2-x_1^TAx_1)\sin^2\alpha > x_1^TAx_1 
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: This can be made into an effective algorithm by picking at each step indices with minimum and maximum $x_i^TAx_i$ and performing a rotation to make one of the values the desired $\frac 1R {\rm Trace}(AX)$.

Comment: I am trying to understand your method. So before starting the algorithm, one needs to solve the function $
\sum_{i} (x_i^TAx_i-\frac 1R{\rm Trace}(AX))^2
$ and find $x_i$? Or can one start with any arbitrary $x_i$ which is a rank-one decomposition of $X$?

Comment: No, not at all: the algorithm does not use the function. Rather, it is based on the rotation idea. First, you pick ANY decomposition into $x_ix_i^T$. Then at each step, you take the "smallest" and the "largest" indices as far as $x_i^TAx_i$ are concerned and consider the rotations above. For some choice of $\cos \alpha$ one will get the correct value of $x^TAx$ (since at $\alpha=0$ the value is too small at $\alpha=\frac \pi 2$ it is too big; also, it is not a terribly hard equation). You replace the two $x$-s by two $y$-s thus increasing the number of indices for which the $x_i^TAx_i$ is OK.

Comment: excellent!. I understood your algorithm. However, I wish I could understand the way the paper has proved it.

Comment: Maybe write to the author?

Answer (score 1):

$$X_1 = RR' - x_1x_1'$$
U is unitary therefore,
$$X_1 = RUIU'R' - \frac{1}{r}RUhh'U'R'$$
Let $M = RU$ then $X = MM'$
So the question becomes whether $MM' - M\frac{hh'}{r}M'$ is psd or not ? so we go to the definition and consider
$$E =  x'MM'x - x'Mhh'M'x/r$$
Let $y=M'x$, so we want to show that $||y||^2 > \langle \frac{h}{\sqrt{r}}, y \rangle^2$

Now this is easily seen if $r == N$ because then $||\frac{h}{\sqrt{r}}||=1$ and cauchy-scwartz kicks in.

I don't have a elegant proof when $r < N$
but the basic idea is that since $X$ has rank $r$ therefore $R \in \mathcal{R}^{N, r}, U \in \mathcal{R}^{r,r}$. We can make the dimensions correct by appending $N-r$ columns of zeros before multiplying $U$ with $h$ but that means we would discard those $N-r$ values and therefore truncate the effective norm of $h$ to be less than $r$.